# Follow crop an object in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking

Since i am a noob video shooter, i'm require to edit those video to "highlight" the person that i actually want to record (the person is too small compare to the image) to do that, i should do a cropping right? but the problem is the video it self actually a bit shaky so i cannot crop the whole thing in one go. I am thinking to implement feature tracking to track the person and link it to cropping mechanism so it will be a steady-focused video, is it can be done? 
Thank you.

Comment: You could use a tracker to follow the person you want highlighted then attach a mask to that. No need to stabilise then.

Answer (score -1):

you can stabilize with tracking you're video in blender.  Here is a youtube tutorial for that:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nU8zqn091rM